# Ruby executable not working

Tags: ruby, linux, shell

On Ubuntu,

I've created an executable file for Ruby with

**bin/hello** (name of the file)

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

But whenever I run `bin/hello` from bin's parent directory

It comes up with `: No such file or directory`

I'm sure there isn't any typo or anything.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail? The error message, for example, looks incomplete. Is there something before the colon (:) or is it really blank like that? Also, is the mode of the file `bin/hello` set to executable?

Comment: I ran chmod +x bin/hello and yes that's all the message I'm getting from shell

Comment: Does it work if you go to the `bin` directory and type, `ruby hello`? Or if you type, `./hello`?

Comment: `ruby hello` is working but not `./hello`

Comment: What shell is first in your $PATH?

Comment: Are you running as root? That would explain why you don't see `/usr/local/bin` and why you have `sbin` paths. If so, DON'T do that. Run as your own user ID and jump in and out of root using `sudo`.

Comment: I'm running as user ID now but still getting the same message...

Comment: Go to the `bin` directory and show what you get when you enter `ls -l hello`.

Comment: `-rwxr-xr-x 1 user user 96 Aug 27 15:31 hello`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's most likely you saved the file with Windows newlines (CRLF); the invisible `CR` before the end of the first line causes the executable search to fail, and part of the error message "erases" itself due to the carriage return.

Look at the file in `vim` and see if `^M` shows up at the end of lines. Alternately, you can look at the output of `xxd bin/hello | head -n 10` and see if `0D 0A` (CR LF) appears. If you suspect CRLF, you can use `dos2unix` to fix the file back to Unix (LF) newlines.

Comment: You are absolutely right. The file was created using my text editor with remote FTP sync from my Windows 8 OS. I basically created the file from shell directly using vim and voila! It worked. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I think this is a really good question and answer as a lot of Windows users might get affected by this if they create *nix executable files via text editor in a local environment

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the file executable

```
chmod +x bin/hello
```

After that run it by writing

```
./bin/hello
```

Comment: `chmod +x` is not to make it **writable**, but **executable**.

Comment: The OP claimed in his comments that he had already done this.